# How Retrive A Piece Of Text From A Source Website With PHP?

Tags: php, html, web

I have to get something that has been shared on a website and it changes every day. but i dont know how to do this. how can i do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible ! however this is not a real question ? we can't just keep guessing, so at leasr provide an exemple of the HTML and the part you need.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results. [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download the exact page you're after using `file_get_contents`

```
$web = file_get_contents("http://google.com")
```

You'd then have to strip out whatever it is you want from the rest of the source code on the website. That can be done by using `strpos` or `stripos` (ipos being case insensitive) to find its location, and then using `substr` to extract that part of the string.